# Why can't templates be deprecated with [[deprecated]]?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, deprecated

C++14 permits the `[[deprecated]]` attribute to be applied to (per 7.6.5/2) "the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a variable, a non-static data member, a function, an enumeration, or a template specialization." Notably missing are templates. So given a template:

```
template<class T>
class MyOldRefCountingPointer {
    ...
};
```

I can deprecate, say, `MyOldRefCountingPointer<void>`,

```
template<>
class
[[deprecated ("Use std::shared_ptr<void> instead of MyOldRefCountingPointer")]]
MyOldRefCountingPointer<void> {
    ...
};
```

but I can't deprecate the general template:

```
template<class T>
class
[[deprecated ("Use std::shared_ptr instead of MyOldRefCountingPointer")]]
MyOldRefCountingPointer {
    ...
};
```

Why is it not permitted to deprecate templates?

#### Update

An example of how a deprecated template can be used without yielding a warning is this:

```
template<class T>
class
[[deprecated]]
OldClass {};

template<template<class> class C = OldClass>   // use deprecated template as
void f()                                       // default template parameter
{
}
```

Neither g++ nor Clang issue warnings here. [Example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccb8f80ce2d0968c).

Answer (score 9):

In C++11 and C++14, **attributes cannot appertain to a template**. Given:

```c++
template<typename T> struct [[deprecated]] C { ... };
```

`[[deprecated]]` appertains to the classes instantiated from the template, *not* to the template itself. In particular, if you write this:

```c++
template<typename T> struct C<T*> { ... };
```

... then `C<int>` is deprecated, but `C<int*>` is not.

The natural way to support deprecation of templates would be to allow an *attribute-specifier-seq* on a *template-declaration*:

```c++
[[attribute]] template<typename T> struct C { ... };
```

... but that syntax is not currently supported, and so far there have been no proposals to add it.

Comment: Downvoted, sorry, because the question was about *why* templates can't be deprecated.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe There is no better reason, sorry. No-one proposed allowing attributes on templates, no-one proposed allowing templates to be deprecated. The default state for a language feature is "does not exist". This answer explains why it wasn't a consequence of the `[[deprecated]]` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure that falls under the general deprecating a class (Same for everything else that can be templated).

Anyway, neither g++ nor clang++ complain: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7c85b4cd4bc036)

Comment: Interesting. So class and function templates are covered under classes and functions, but function template specializations are not covered under functions. Weird.

Comment: Hmm... I would have thought it falls under the *specialization* part. À la "The template itself is not deprecated, but all specializations it produces."

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe You can deprecate template classes (they are classes) and template functions (they are functions), but you can't deprecate class templates (they are not classes, they're templates) nor function templates (they are not functions, they're templates).

Comment: I've unselected Deduplicator's answer as the accepted solution, because additional testing (prompted by R. Martinho Fernandes's comment) led me to several ways to make use of templates with the `[[deprecated]]` attribute without getting a warning with g++ 4.9.1 or Clang 3.6. Such templates can be used as default values for template template parameters, for example, and it's also possible to get pointers to member functions (static or non-static) of a deprecated template class. So it seems that my question stands: why *can't* templates be deprecated?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Please add your findings. Also, a link to Coliru, ideone or some other online-compiler showing them would be good.

Comment: Any idea how to get a URL for a specific example at [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) or [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)? Wandbox doesn't seem to have any help, and the Q&A for Coliru doesn't seem to discuss getting URLs.

Comment: On coliru: Enter your code, compile, click share. Copy the URL of the current page. For more changes, click edit. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4518951542e218f5

Comment: @Deduplicator: I added an example to the main post and linked to Coliru, but the link goes to an edit page (which is what comes up when "Share" is linked), not to the page where you can run the code. Any further tips on how I can create a proper link?

Comment: You know, neither template is ODR-used, thus deprecated should not trigger. The way I understand it.